# Matrix Norm Inequalities

Tags: matrices, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given $$\Vert A x_0 - {A'} {x_0'} \Vert_2 \leq  \beta_1 $$ and $$ \Vert x_0 - x'_0 \Vert_2 \leq \beta_2 $$  where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n $, can we find $\gamma_{min}, \gamma_{max} > 0 $  such that the following relationship holds $$\gamma_{min} \leq \Vert A - A' \Vert_2 \leq \gamma_{max} $$

Comment: I doubt it since for $x_0=x'_0$ you have the inequality for any matrix...

Comment: You need at least $n$ points $x_1,\dots,x_n$ in place of $x_0'$, for getting $n$ independent directions [$(x_i-x_0)_i$ forming a basis]  for guaranteeing such $\gamma$'s for *one* matrix $A$.